# How to install . NET Programmability Support in office 2010

Tags: installation, ms-office

I have struggled to install .NET Programmability Support in office 2010.

I have done it through "programs and features" , but still I see  a red "X" then it saying "Not available".

Would you please help me to install .NET Programmability Support in Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

To install .NET Programmability Support you need to first install a version of the .NET Framework >= 2.0.